# greatest sum sub array such that each element is less than or equal to X

Tags: algorithm

Given an array A with N integers we need to find the highest sum of sub array such that each element is less than or equal to given integer X

Example : Let N=8 and array be [3 2 2 3 1 1 1 3] . Now if x=2 then answer is 4 by summing A[2] + A[3] if we consider 1 base indexing . How to do this question in O(N) or O(N*logN)

Currently am having O(N^2) approach by checking each possible subarray. How to reduce the complexity ?

Comment: You mentioned longest sub array, but in your example the answer is subarray with greatest sum. What do you need of these variants?

Comment: @citxx Yeah by longest subarray I mean greatest sum..sorry

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood your question so I deleted my answer. (mixed each element <= x for total sum <= x).

Comment: The stated problem is equivalent to the maximum subarray with every element greater than X essentially counting for -inf. You can apply [Kadane's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) trivially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that if some array contain integers only less than or equal to `X`, then all its subarrays also have this property. Lets find for each index `i` the greatest possible sum of subarray, ending at `i` (`sub_sum`).

```
sub_sum[i] = 0, if array[i] > X
sub_sum[i] = max(array[i], sub_sum[i - 1] + array[i]), otherwise
```

Initial conditions are:

```
sub_sum[1] = 0, if array[1] > X
sub_sum[1] = max(array[1], 0), otherwise
```

You can compute all `sub_sum` values in one loop using the formulas above. The answer to your question is the maximum in `sub_sum` array. The computation complexity is **O(n)**.

Answer (score 1):

I am just giving you a simple step by step approach

---

### Time complexity O(n) Space complexity O(n)

```
1. Input array=A[1..n] and x be the element and ans= -INF
```

(smallest int value)

```
2. Take another array B[1..n]={0,0,...0}.

3. For i=1 to n 
    if(A[i]<=x)
     B[i]=1;

sum=0;
4. For i=1 to n
    if(B[i])
    sum+=A[i];
    else
    {
    ans=maximum of(sum,ans);
    sum= 0;
    }
5. ans is the output.
```

### Time complexity O(n) Space complexity O(1)

```
Note ans= -INF;(smallest int value)
     sum=0;

1. for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   //get input Ai in variable a(temporary int variable to store the elements)
   if(a<=x)
    sum+=a
   else
   {
    ans=max of (ans,sum);
    sum= 0;
   }

2. ans will be the output.
```

Comment: @greybeard.: a is an int variable. And by minus INF I wanted to mean the lowest integer possible.

Comment: @greybeard.: Ok! I have corrected it. Please check.

Comment: Doesn't look wrong. For the need for `B`, see Michael Foukarakis' comment to the question and pertaining answers.

Answer (score 0):

An O(n) C++ code:

```
const int INF = 2147483647;
int A[] = {3,2,2,3,1,1,1,3};
int ArraySize = 8;

int X = 2;



int max = -INF; //currenly max
int si = -1; //starting index
int ei = -1; //ending index
int tmax = 0; //temp currenly max
int tsi = -1; //temp starting index
int tei = -1; //temp ending index


for (int i = 0;i<ArraySize;i++) {
    if (A[i]<=X) {
        tmax+=A[i];
        if (tsi==-1) tsi = i;
    }
    else {
        tei = i-1;
        if (tmax>max) {
            max = tmax;
            si = tsi;
            ei = tei;
        }
        tsi = -1;
        tei = -1;
        tmax = 0;
    }
}
cout<<"Max is: "<<max<<" starting from "<<si<<" ending to "<<ei<<"\n";
```